# Match number between 2 date

Tags: regex, vb.net

I got a text and I need to extract a number that is between 2 dates. I can't show the full text so I will only use the part I need, but keep in mint it's part of a bigger text.

> 12/14/2020 355345 12/14/2020

From that, I need to get '355345', I currently don't have anything to show of what I was doing because I was working on getting the text before a sentence, until I realized it the only place where the number is between 2 dates.

Thanks!

Comment: Do they have to be valid dates, or will `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}` suffice?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't need to validate, as long as the format is correct so that work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet that might help:

Suppose the input is this:

```vb
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

'...

Dim input As New StringBuilder

input.AppendLine("12/14/2020 355345 12/14/2020")
input.AppendLine("12/13/2020 425345 12/13/2020")
input.AppendLine("12/20/2020 93488557 12/20/2020")
input.AppendLine("12/21/2020 4 12/21/2020")
input.AppendLine("12/20/2020 3443 12/20/2020")

'...
```

Use [RegEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) to extract the numbers between the two dates as follows:

```vb
Dim patt = "(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\s?(\d+)\s?(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)"

For Each m In Regex.
    Matches(input.ToString, patt, RegexOptions.Multiline).
    Cast(Of Match)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(2).Value)
Next
```

This will capture three groups. Example for the first match:

- `m.Groups(1).Value` : 12/14/202 the first date.
- `m.Groups(2).Value` : 355345 the number in between.
- `m.Groups(3).Value` : 12/14/2020 the second date.

If you have no use for the captured dates, then no need to get theme grouped and use the following pattern instead:

```vb
Dim patt = "\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s?(\d+)\s?\d+\/\d+\/\d+"

For Each m In Regex.
    Matches(input.ToString, patt, RegexOptions.Multiline).
    Cast(Of Match)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
Next
```

And you will get the number between the two dates in Group 1.

The output of both is:

```
355345
425345
93488557
4
3443
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ou5ruY/20)

Also, using the [quantifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions) in RegEx patterns is a good idea as Mr. @AndrewMorton mentioned in his appreciated comments, and that to skip any possible things like `1234/239994/2293` in the input:

```vb
Dim patt = "\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\s(\d{1,})\s\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"

For Each m In Regex.
    Matches(input.ToString, patt, RegexOptions.Multiline).
    Cast(Of Match)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
Next
```

The quantifiers-way test is [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ou5ruY/23).

Answer (score 0):

If you can safely check for numbers and slashes, then a pattern like this should work:

```
\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d +(\d+) +\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d
```

...where capture group 1 would hold the number being sought. If you need to validate that the values are actually dates, well...  you can do it with regex to a degree, but the pattern becomes very difficult to read.

Comment: work :) I will wait abit before giving the mark sign incase anything else come up to blow my mind! As we never know in this site haha!

Thanks!

Comment: noticed that actually take the 2 dates also in the result, I would only need the number, not the date =(

Comment: The capture group would give you the number part. That can be referenced from the `Groups` property of [a `Match` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?view=netframework-4.8).